# FileSystem lock while creating Indexer

Tags: lucene, spring-data-jpa, microservices, hibernate-search

I have used hibernate-search where I have annotated the domains with `@Indexed`, `@Field` and many more.
My project is based on multiple microservices like

1. Search Service - which upon starting read the data from DB and create the indexes. (code has been mentioned below):

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void initializeHibernateSearch() {
    try {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(centityManager);
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

2. MicroService 1 - which updates the index when any domain is inserted or updated.

The issue I am facing is that when `Search Service` is started and creates the indexes, it takes the locks on the index files and never releases the locks.
and when Microservice 1 tries to update the index upon insertion or update, it throws an exception as below

> org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: /root/data/index/default/Event/write.lock
>           at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
>           at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
>           at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
>           at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:776)
>           at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:126)
>           at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:92)
>           at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:117)
>           at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:203)
>           at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.applyUpdates(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:81)
>           at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.run(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:46)
>           at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.applyChangesets(SyncWorkProcessor.java:166)
>           at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:152)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Could you please let me know what is the right approach to use hibernate-search in microservices architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options. My recommendation is the first one, as it best fits the architectural spirit of Micro services.

1. Each micro service has an independent index: don't share the index directory.
2. Use the master/slave architecture described [in the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-architecture), so to have a single service write to the index - the other services will have to delegate to the single writer. Indexes can be replicated over network based filesystem, or using Infinispan.
3. Disable *exclusive_index_use*, a configuration property (also described in the docs). I'm listing this for completeness, but this is generally a bad idea; it's going to be much slower and it's going to be your responsibility that one service busy writing won't timeout another service needing to write.

Comment: Thanks Sanne for multiple solutions. Yes you are right, approach 1 is the one which we should use when implementing microservices.